# Installing windows 7 on two computers ~ 1 serial key

Tags: windows-7, installation

Just a quick one. I have two computers, but only one copy of Windows 7. I know **legally** I should have two separate license keys, however, I am just wondering what would happen if I installed it on the two computers using one license?

Just to satisfy my curiosity of course :)

Comment: At best one you wouldn't be allowed to activate the second copy, at worst both would be deactivated. This is a duplicate BTW - I just can't find it at the moment.

Comment: So if we tell you it works w/o trouble you are not going to do it because it's not sooo correct, from a legal point of view ;)

Comment: Of course ;-) Just something I always wondered about :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would be unable to activate it, and it would stop working after a number of days.

Answer (score -1):

Unknown to most people, retail Microsoft Software Licensing (for Windows 7, Office) allows for installation on ONE main use PC and ONE portable PC, as long as both are not in use simultaneously.

See [here](http://www.microsoft.com/About/Legal/EN/US/IntellectualProperty/UseTerms/Default.aspx)

Comment: Did you actually look at your link?  While Office does include this right, Windows does not.  I searched for Windows 7 Home Premium English in a retail package and surprise...its for one computer only.